# Segmentation fault || String manipulation using c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

Can any one please guide me through this:
as i try to execute my program without any compilation error, i get a segmentation fault error while copying the characters from one string to another string.For reference- My program finds out the most occurring sub-string of specified length from a string

my code is as follows:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* format(char* str,int l);
void main(){
    char *str=malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    char *sub;
    int i;
    printf("\n Enter the string : ");
    fgets(str,1024,stdin);
    printf("\n");
    puts(str);
    printf("\nEnter max no of char for substrings:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    sub=malloc(i*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(sub,format(str,i));
    printf("\nSubstring : %s",sub);
    free(str);
}
char* format(char* str,int l){
    int i,j,k,x,max,pos;
    int len =strlen(str);
    int *arr=(int*)malloc(len*sizeof(int));
    char **subs =(char**)malloc(len*l*sizeof(char));

    printf("\n test 1 %s %d",str,l);
    for(i=0;i<len-l;i++){
        for(j=0;j<l;j++){
            *(*(subs+i)+j)=*(str+i+j);
        }
    }
    printf("\n test 2");
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            x=strcmp(subs[i],subs[j]);
            if(x==0){
                arr[i]=arr[j]+1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n test 3");
    max=arr[0];
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max=arr[1];
            pos=i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n test 4");
    return subs[i];
}
```

after passing test 1 in function format() the program stops responding.

```
 for(i=0;i<len-l;i++){
        for(j=0;j<l;j++){
            *(*(subs+i)+j)=*(str+i+j);
        }
    }
```

please guide me through this,your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `void main()` is not standard-compliant. `main()` should return an `int` which is the exit status of the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

`sub=malloc(i*sizeof(char));` Allocates space for `i`x`char`, not `i`x`char*`.

Even if you got this right (`sizeof(char*)`) you still need to allocate each member of that array so there is space to copy into.

...And lets not even start on the memory leaks...

Comment: can you clarify a bit?

Comment: What is to clarify? You have not allocated memory correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `char **subs` is not appropriate. `*(*(sub + i) + j)` dose not point at what you expect.

See an example `*(*(sub + 1) + 2)`.

Firstly, `sub + 1`

```
|char| ... *6 ... |char|'c'|char| ... |

^                      ^
|                      |
sub                    sub+1
```

In above case, `*(sub + 1)` just is equal with 'c'.

Then, `*(sub + 1) + 2` just is equal with `'c'+2`, which is a unknown address.

Finally, `*(*(sub + 1) + 2)` means accessing the content whose address is `'c'+2`.

I suggest:

```
char *array = malloc(sizeof(char) * cols * rows);

// Access element at (row=i, col=j)
// Use []
array[i * cols + j] = 'c';
// Or use *()
*(array + i * cols + j) = 'c';
```